# How to display JSON Data in UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, json

i have the following JSON Data, which is a respond from my Webservice.

```
     {"d": [{"raumKlassenObject":"Telepresenzraum"},
{"raumKlassenObject":"Besprechungsraum"},
{"raumKlassenObject":"Videokonferenzraum"},
{"raumKlassenObject":"IT-Schulungsraum"},
{"raumKlassenObject":"Konferenzraum"}]}
```

How can i display the Data Telepresenzraum, Besprechungsraum etc... in a TableView.

Heres my Code so far.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:result options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    array = [dic allKeys];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return array.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dic objectForKey:@"d"]];    



return cell;
}
```

If i do it like that the output in the Tableview is

```
 [{"raumKlassenObject":"Telepresenzraum"},{"raumKlassenObject":"Besprechungsraum"},{"raumKlassenObject":"Videokonferenzraum"},{"raumKlassenObject":"IT-Schulungsraum"},{"raumKlassenObject":"Konferenzraum"}]
```

I dont know how to display only Telepresenzraum, Besprechungsraum, Videokonferenzraum etc.. in  tableview rows.

Thx for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You top level dictionary only has one key,"d", so array.count will be 1 and the [dic objectForKey:@"d"] will be the whole array of dictionaries.

So, to fix this redefine array as:

```
array = [[dic valueForKey:@"d"] valueForKey:@"raumKlassenObject"];
```

This should give you an array of all the values for that key. Then, replace the first line below with the second:

```
cell.textLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dic objectForKey:@"d"]]; 
cell.textLabel.text= [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a nil-check for `cell`.  It **will** be nil until you have scrolled a bit.  If it is nil, you need to actually create the cell using the UITableView cell class init methods.

Comment: i did that now, but thats not fixing my Problem/Question

Comment: `cell.textLabel.text=[dic objectForKey:[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];`

Comment: its still the same output  [{"raumKlassenObject":"Telepresenzraum"},{"raumKlassenObject":"Besprechungsraum"},{"raumKlassenObject":"Videokonferenzraum"},{"raumKlassenObject":"IT-Schulungsraum"},{"raumKlassenObject":"Konferenzraum"}].

Comment: That is the only entry in your dictionary.  What you have is an array of dictionaries, each with only one entry.  So actually what you need is...`[[[dic objectForKey@"d"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey@"raumKlassenObject"];`.

Comment: i tried your solutions, but i get an Error [__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Then your JSON is not as you indicated in your question.  It seems the entire entry is being read as a string instead of an array.  Double check your JSON.

Comment: i checked my webservice and changed it a little. Now i use [[dic objectForKey:@"d"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];. Its now returning Telepresenzraum. Iam Close :). But how can i display all?